# rm error when installing Pow: "Permission denied"

Tags: rm, rack-pow

I wanted to install Pow. Running `curl get.pow.cx | sh` in my home directory yields :

```
*** Installing Pow 0.3.2...
rm: Current: Permission denied
```

Adding `sudo` in front didn't change anything.

Hope this is not a newbie question, and relevant to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the shell script you are downloading with `curl get.pow.cx` is trying to remove a directory/link named `Current`, but lacks sufficient privileges or the directory/link does not exist. You may need to perform the operation from within the user's home directory on your machine. The program will take care of putting the files in the relevant directories (at least it should).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Deleting /Application Support/pow fixed it. It was a due to an accidental recursive (!!) permission change on my "Application Support" folder. Sorry for the newbie problem!